# Windows Azure Project - windows service Error 1053 The service did not respond to the start or control request in timely fashion

Tags: azure, windows-services

I have created one Windows Azure project in .net framework 4, visual studio 2010.

Windows Azure SDK version is 1.8.

I have created one windows service to accomplish the running of daily Scheduled tasks.

Below is the code for that -

```
public partial class EdService1 : ServiceBase
{ 
public EdService1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region On Start
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        //Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServiceStart));
        //thread.IsBackground = true;
        //thread.Name = "ThreadServiceStart";
        //thread.Start();
        #region Email Utility timer set and call
        try
        {
        TraceService("start service");
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.ServiceTimer_Tick);
            this.timer.Interval = 300000;//300000; //60000 millisecond = 1 minute
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
            ServiceTimer_Tick(null, null);
        #endregion

            #region Daily Utility timer set and call
            Dailytimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            Dailytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.DailyTimer_Tick);
            this.Dailytimer.Interval = 7200000; //60000 millisecond = 1 minute
            Dailytimer.AutoReset = true;
            Dailytimer.Enabled = true;
            Dailytimer.Start();
            DailyTimer_Tick(null, null);
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public void ServiceStart()
    {
        #region Email Utility timer set and call
    TraceService("start service");
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.ServiceTimer_Tick);
        this.timer.Interval = 300000;//300000; //60000 millisecond = 1 minute
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
        ServiceTimer_Tick(null, null);
        #endregion

        #region Daily Utility timer set and call
        Dailytimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Dailytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.DailyTimer_Tick);
        this.Dailytimer.Interval = 7200000; //60000 millisecond = 1 minute
        Dailytimer.AutoReset = true;
        Dailytimer.Enabled = true;
        Dailytimer.Start();
        DailyTimer_Tick(null, null);
        #endregion
    }

    #region Sending Email Utility
    private void ServiceTimer_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        strErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        string strEmailError = "";

        try
        {
            // calling functions here

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
        }

        if (strErrorMessage != "")
        {
            string strIPAddress = GetLocalIPAddress();

            SendEmail("Error in Sending Email Utility " + strIPAddress, strErrorMessage.Replace("#", "\n </br>"), EmailFrom, EmailTo, ref strEmailError, EmailCC);
        }

     }

private void TraceService(string content)
    {

        //set up a filestream
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\ScheduledService.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        //set up a streamwriter for adding text
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

        //find the end of the underlying filestream
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

        //add the text
        sw.WriteLine(content);
        //add the text to the underlying filestream

        sw.Flush();
        //close the writer
        sw.Close();
    }
  protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Enabled = false;
        TraceService("stopping service");
    }
```

I tried to start this service with local and administrator account. But getting this mentioned error message.

Even I am not sure how to test this methods onStart() for this service. I tried diagnostics code but it doesn't stop there.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Put a bunch of trace statements in, download the trace, and see how far it gets. I assume it works in the emulator but does not work on a real instance?

Comment: It doesn't work at all on any instance. I am trying to put this trace service method to see what happens from this link. http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/creating-windows-service-in-c-or.html     ******** will let you know the results. Thanks

Comment: Hello, please check my code, I have put trace method, it didn't do anything. I don't think so it is calling this service onstart method at all. Any idea?

Comment: Hey, I tried to put exe with dlls in different folder, and then created test service, it is running fine. I am getting above error message when this service is created automatically by the project. What could be the reason?

Comment: Also, found below error in event log. Exception: The type initializer for 'EdUtility.EdService1' threw an exception.